# Get full hexdump of parsed packet in Pyshark

Tags: python, pyshark

I am using [Pyshark](https://github.com/KimiNewt/pyshark) to parse packet from pcap file. 
I have object of parsed packet. Separately I can get hex_value of each fields after changed raw_mode attribute to True.

```
>>> packet = pyshark.FileCapture("ip_packet.pcap")
>>> packet_1 = packet[0]
>>> packet_1.layers()
[<ETH Layer>, <IP Layer>, <DATA Layer>]
>>> packet_1.ip.addr
'192.168.1.5'

>>> packet_1.ip.raw_mode = True
>>> packet_1.ip.addr
'c0a80105'
```

How can I get hexdump of full packet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot at the moment. 
Pyshark parses the output of tshark which does not contain the original packet bytes. You can try "reassembling" the packet yourself but I wouldn't recommend it.

As it stands, this feature can be added but is not possible at the moment, if you want that specifically I suggest you use a different package or parse only the packets (without any protocols) yourself or using [construct](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/construct) (or other similar packages).

Comment: does that mean we cannot get the size (in MB) of the data transferred ?

Comment: You can (since that's parsed by wireshark) - just use pkt.captured_length

Answer (score -1):

If you need to parse your packet (before having the hexdump of full packet) you may have you a look on [pyshark_parser](https://github.com/jlents/pyshark_parser)

Comment: On the github project, we can read: "Looking for contributors - for various reasons I have a hard time finding time to maintain and enhance the package at the moment. Any pull-requests will be reviewed and if any one is interested and is suitable, I will be happy to include them in the project.

Comment: This project has no documentation, could you please refer me to the class or method which gives the hexdump value of a packet? I cannot seem to find it.

Comment: there is no such functions